# File uploader in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement file uploader in `angularJS` but with a condition that if input file is empty it should give a massage. 
I used following code:

```
if(var inputFileLength=document.getElementById("#id").value==0) 
alert ("input file is empty");
```

But it is not working. So please give some solution for the same.

Comment: Do we really need angularjs mention in tag, body and title? This appears to be pretty much a generic JS question

Answer (score 1):

I believe `value` will get the filename, so that won't work.

We can get details of the selected files using `event.target.files`, and use the `.size` property.

Try this:

```js
function selected(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file.size === 0) {
    alert("Its empty");
  } else {
    alert("size is " + file.size);
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="selected(event)" />
```

This is not supported on IE < 11 though...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File